# Accessing Network Connections Logs w/Nougat

Tags: stock-android

I'm no programmer and I can't code for crap but I've suffered some breaches when my VPN disconnects. I only use data but I'd sure love access to the logs

Comment: Thanks Guys, I'm going to try every suggestion people took the time to answer my questions

Answer (score 0):

I think the radio logs would help and maybe just a standard logcat.

First, you must have ADB installed on your computer.

You must have ADB Debugging enabled on your device.

Plug your device into your computer.

Open an elevated command prompt.

Check to see if your device is seen with the command:

adb devices

Your device should ask you allow usb debugging with an RSA key click o.k.

Once it is seen then throw this command to get the radio logs:

adb logcat -b radio -v time -d > logcat_radio.log

That will create a text of the radio logs on your computer.

As for the standard logcat then just throw this command. The -v long part will give you the most info. It will put a text on your desktop:

With Windows:

adb logcat -v long > %userprofile%\desktop\logcat.txt

Or with Linux:

adb logcat -v long > ~/Desktop/logcat.txt